# Why do some keys become seperated columns in the merged dataframe using outer method?

Tags: pandas

df1:

| Reporting Country | v2x_regime_rep | Year | v2x_regime_partner | FDI_inward |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Albania | 0.0 | 1995 | 0.0 | NaN |
| Albania | 0.0 | 1995 | 1.0 | NaN |
| Albania | 0.0 | 1996 | 0.0 | NaN |
| Albania | 0.0 | 1996 | 1.0 | NaN |

df2:

| Reporting Country | v2x_regime_rep | Year | v2x_regime_partner | FDI_outward |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Australia | 1.0 | 1995 | 0.0 | 4.694731 |
| Australia | 1.0 | 1995 | 1.0 | 203.394006 |
| Australia | 1.0 | 1996 | 0.0 | 49.822881 |
| Australia | 1.0 | 1996 | 1.0 | 49.822881 |

I would like to merge two datasets, using the keys that are Reporting Country, v2x_regime_rep, Year, v2x_regime_partner. However, in the end I end up with 8 columns whereas I would like to have following shape:

| Reporting Country | v2x_regime_rep | Year | v2x_regime_partner | FDI_outward | FDI_inward |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Australia | 1.0 | 1995 | 0.0 | 4.694731 | 5.0000 |
| Australia | 1.0 | 1995 | 1.0 | 203.394006 | 9.822881 |
| Australia | 1.0 | 1996 | 0.0 | 49.822881 | 20.822881 |
| Australia | 1.0 | 1996 | 1.0 | 49.822881 | 45.822881 |

It is important that even if FDI_inward or FDI_outward is NaN, I would like to keep them because while one of them being NaN other one might have a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample you gave for `df1` is incomplete.

Try one of these solutions :

With [**`pandas.merge`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) :

```
new_df = (
            df2.merge(df1, on=list(df2.columns[:-1]), how='outer')
               .dropna(subset=['FDI_inward', 'FDI_outward'], how='any')
               .reset_index(drop=True)
         )
```

With [**`pandas.concat`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) :

```
new_df_ = (
            pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)
              .groupby(list(df1.columns[:-1]), as_index=False).first()
              .dropna(subset=['FDI_inward', 'FDI_outward'], how='any')
              .reset_index(drop=True)
          )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(new_df)

  Reporting Country  v2x_regime_rep  Year  v2x_regime_partner  FDI_outward  FDI_inward
0         Australia             1.0  1995                 0.0     4.694731    5.000000
1         Australia             1.0  1995                 1.0   203.394006    9.822881
2         Australia             1.0  1996                 0.0    49.822881   20.822881
3         Australia             1.0  1996                 1.0    49.822881   45.822881
```